# Removing garbage output from empty lines while reading a csv file to an array of structs in C

Tags: c, arrays, file, csv, struct

I am creating a program to read the elements of a csv file to an array of structs. I have the part down of reading the csv file and storing it as instructed. However, my output is printing more than the elements needed and printing garbage afterwards. Any recommendations on how to go about removing this extra output. Any recommendations would be appreciated!
Below is the input from the csv file.

```
Mark IV Deluxe,21.99,5
Super Professional,14.49,55
Grand Super Deluxe,99.99,99
Awesome Deluxe,149.99,2
Deluxe 2000,20,92
Nearly Deluxe 200,19.99,23
Almost Awesome Mark II,10.49,56
Revised Model 2.5,25.49,8
Potentially Professioanl Mark IV,12.99,77
Suboptimal Super 500,99.49,27
Less Than Stelar 600 Mark III,6.99,42
```

This is my code so far.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#define MAX_ARRAY_ELEM 64

struct stock {

    char name_item[MAX_ARRAY_ELEM];
    float price;
    int stock_num;
};

void print_iteration(struct stock stuff[], int size);
void stock_print_state( struct product_info d );

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    struct stock info[MAX_ARRAY_ELEM];
    char heading[MAX_ARRAY_ELEM];


    FILE * fp;
    fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");


    int f = 0;
    if (fp == NULL) {
        printf("No file provided.\n");
    }

    else if (fp != NULL) {

        fscanf(fp, "%s\n", heading);
        while(fscanf(fp, "%[^,],%f,%d", info[f].name_item,
        &info[f].price, &info[f].stock_num) == 3) {
            f++;
        }
    }
    fclose(fp);
    print_iteration(info, MAX_ARRAY_ELEM); //change MAX_ARRAY_ELEM to f that was       
                                           //incremented above
}

void stock_print_state(struct stock s){

    printf("%s: $%0.2f \n", s.item, s.item_price * s.num_of_items);
}

void print_iteration(struct stock stocks[], int arr_elems) {

    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < arr_elems; i++) {
        print_products(stocks[i]);
    }
}
```

Below is the output that I'm receiving.

Mark IV Deluxe: $109.95

Super Professional: $796.95

Grand Super Deluxe: $9899.01

Awesome Deluxe: $299.98

Deluxe 2000: $1840.00

Nearly Deluxe 200: $459.77

Almost Awesome Mark II: $587.44

Revised Model 2.5: $203.92

Potentially Professioanl Mark IV: $1000.23

Suboptimal Super 500: $2686.23

Less Than Stelar 600 Mark III: $293.58

: $0.00
: $0.00
: $0.00
: $0.00
: $35742271459613871000000000000000.00
: $0.00
≡Kal·: $35686921999888634000000000000000.00
└±b: $36957000123162650000000000000000.00
┬Ial·: $0.00
csmα: $-1.#R
: $35487717621184175000000000000000.00
dgl·: $0.00
0: $38133850722931264000000000000000.00
: $36668845400502585000000000000000.00
÷b: $1.#R
|: $0.00
: $0.00
: $0.00
à■: $38133850722931264000000000000000.00
: $38388544796756035000000000000000.00
: $38135492444194300000000000000000.00
PÉ@: $0.00
d{ql·: $0.00
: $0.00
: $0.00
p]|: $0.00
(: $0.00
D: $0.00
▒ïol·: $0.00
: $0.00
: $37912730936968830000000000000000.00
: $0.00
: $0.00
: $0.00
: $0.00
α^|: $0.00
: $0.00
H: $0.00
: $0.00
8: $0.00
: $0.00
: $0.00
: $0.00
 : $0.00
: $-0.00
 z@: $0.00
H: $0.00
: $0.00
: $0.00
: $0.00
ùtl·: $35907625915369120000000000000000.00
8: $0.00
: $0.00

### Total: -1.#R

Process exited after 0.03642 seconds with return value 12
Press any key to continue . . .

Comment: I am not a scanf user, so the question might be dumb, but doesn't your second scanf miss a "\n" in his format string ? If I had to parse a csv, I think i would have iterated over the input line by line, then just split with strtok on the separating character and parse it token by token.

Comment: `"%[^,],%f,%d"` does not consume the end-of-line `'\n'`.  Certainly read and save in next iteration into `list[elem_plus].item`.  Please post a [mcve]

Comment: Hi @Aali! It would help if you copy & paste your output into the question instead of using a link to a screen shot.

Comment: Yes, I'm working on producing a minimal example. I will also post the output, in just a moment!

Comment: I posted both the minimal example and the output that I'm receiving.

Comment: @chux: So, you're saying to do a "%[^\n]" at the end and map to the info[f].name_item or add '\n'  to the %[^,\n]?

Comment: I recommend to read the _line_ of file input with `fgets()`, then parse the line.  Set aside `fscanf(), scanf()`.  `sscanf()` is good.

Comment: @AaliEddie You have not posted your input.  How about the first few lines of the file?

Comment: "my output is reading more than the elements needed and printing garbage afterwards." No.  Output is not reading too many.   Output is printing too many.  Try `print_iteration(info, MAX_ARRAY_ELEM);` --> `print_iteration(info, f);`

Comment: Ok, I will edit that in my question. I added the input as asked. That seemed to help, changing to the f. Not sure how I didn't pick up on that simple mistake. I'll update in the body for the question, thanks for the advice!